# Focus an inline jQuery UI Datepicker for the keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, accessibility

I've been searching the net for an answer or sample of this but have come up short so far.

jQuery UI gives some great "out of the box" keyboard shortcuts for the Datepicker widget, but they only seem to work if the widget is opened after you focus / click inside an associated input box.

I'm using an "inline" version of the Datepicker attached to a div tag, and am trying to figure out a way to focus it so I can still use the keyboard shortcuts that come standard from the jQuery UI. (For keyboard accessibility)

Has anyone done this? Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I fully understand the question, but a common practice is to add `tabindex="-1"` to elements before moving focus with JavaScript.

**Edit:**

Okay, I looked into this a little further.  All keycode events are filtered through a control statement which checks to see if the _datepickerShowing property is set to true.  This property is set to false in the constructor.  The only way to set _datepickerShowing to true is through _showDatepicker, BUT it has to pass through this:

```
if (!inst.inline) {
    // ...
    $.datepicker._datepickerShowing = true;
```

_datepickerShowing will also be set to false as soon as you hit tab.

I found this article on how to [Show Hide jQuery UI DatePicker Programmatically](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/04/show-hide-jquery-ui-datepicker.html) but it's obviously meant for the input datepicker and [fails a simple test I made with jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fk10hysn/3/).

Outside of forking the library or posting an issue on github, I think it's a lost cause.

Perhaps there's a way to configure the input type to meet you needs.  What exactly is the effect you would like?  Always showing?

Comment: Thanks for responding, but thats not the issue.  If you are familiar with jQuery UI, there are basically two types of datepickers: one that is a popup for input boxes or buttons, and, one that is "inline" or assigned to a div or span, and always there.  jQuery has some cool keyboard functions for the popup, but no way to use them in the "inline" version.

Comment: I appreciate your comments.  Yes, the Datepicker will always be showing as part of a homepage.  I did bypass this issue by using some jquery and javascript to handle events using the classes of the calendar elements.  I may post it as an answer alternative here.

Comment: @Maulzal - please do, I'm having the same problem :).

Comment: Stephen, sorry for the late response, I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For Stephen Harris,  here is an example of some of the JavaScript I used to focus things like previous and next on the inline calendar, and execute clicks with enter key:

```
        $(".ui-datepicker td a.calendar-event").attr("tabindex", "0");
        $(".ui-datepicker td a.calendar-event").addClass("focus-element-flag");
        $("#datepicker").on('keydown', '.calendar-event', function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                $(this).trigger("click");
                $(".ui-datepicker-prev").focus();
            }
        });

        $("#datepicker").on('keydown', '.ui-datepicker-prev', function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                $(this).trigger("click");
                $(".ui-datepicker-prev").focus();
            }
        });
        $("#datepicker").on('keydown', '.ui-datepicker-next', function (e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                $(this).trigger("click");
                $(".ui-datepicker-next").focus();
            }
        });
```